# How can I detect if Flash is installed and if not, display a hidden div that informs the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, flash, detection

How can I use javascript/jQuery/etc to detect if Flash is installed and if it isn't, display a div that contains information informing the user that they need to install flash?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use swfobject. it replaces a div with the flash if it is installed.
see: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 159):

If `swfobject` won't suffice, or you need to create something a little more bespoke, try this:

```js
var hasFlash = false;
try {
    hasFlash = Boolean(new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'));
} catch(exception) {
    hasFlash = ('undefined' != typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']);
}
```

It works with 7 and 8.

Comment: this works nice if you just want to detect if it is installed and not necessarily display a swf either way.

Comment: Had to modify this to: var hasFlash = false;
  try {
    var fo = (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']) ? navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin : 0;
    if(fo) hasFlash = true;
  }catch(e){
    if(navigator.mimeTypes ['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
  }"

Comment: that won't work on IE7, as you're not testing the activexobject part

Comment: upvote for using 5 lines of JavaScript instead of using an entire library

Comment: This will work for android mobile browser like firefox and chrome ?

Comment: nice solution, but in the catch case I prefer to check : `(typeof navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] !== 'undefined')`

Comment: solution was not working for ubuntu14.04  firefox(44.0) but @inverrtedSpear with your changes solution worked fine.

Comment: This is only working if the user hasn't installed Flash Player, but it's not working if it's installed but deactivated.

Comment: What if the flash is out of date ? Safari sometimes says it's out of date and it won't work until you update. How would I check for that?

Answer (score 105):

@Drewid's answer didn't work in my Firefox 25 if the flash plugin is just disabled but installed.

@invertedSpear's comment in that answer worked in firefox but not in any IE version.

So combined both their code and got this. Tested in Google Chrome 31, Firefox 25, IE 8-10. Thanks Drewid and invertedSpear :)

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if (fo) {
    hasFlash = true;
  }
} catch (e) {
  if (navigator.mimeTypes
        && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined
        && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin) {
    hasFlash = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works in Firefox 39 (2015-08-03).

Comment: It doesn't work if plugin are allowed but Flash is explicitely blocked for the website we are checking. Safari 8.0.8. In this case hasFlash is still true (should be false).

Comment: No longer works in Firefox 50+ tested 2017, still says "true" when I "block" flash from running on website.

Comment: how do we dispose fo object afterwards?

Comment: seems like it is taking up memory and not release everytime this code runs. IE11 on win 7 specifically

Answer (score 18):

You can use navigator.mimeTypes.

```
if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] == undefined)
    $("#someDiv").show ();
```

Answer (score 10):

jqplugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqplugin/

```
$.browser.flash == true
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also be able to use..

```
swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion().major === 0
```

with the [swfobject-Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Comment: `swfobject` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I used Adobe's detection kit, originally suggested by justpassinby. Their system is nice because it detects the version number and compares it for you against your 'required version'

One bad thing is it does an alert showing the detected version of flash, which isn't very user friendly. All of a sudden a box pops up with some seemingly random numbers.

Some modifications you might want to consider:

- remove the alert
- change it so it returns an object (or array)
  --- first element is boolean true/false for "was the required version found on user's machine"
  --- second element is the actual version number found on user's machine

Answer (score 1):

Very very minified version of http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html (only boolean flash detection)

```
var isFlashInstalled = (function(){
var b=new function(){var n=this;n.c=!1;var a="ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash",r=[{name:a+".7",version:function(n){return e(n)}},{name:a+".6",version:function(n){var a="6,0,21";try{n.AllowScriptAccess="always",a=e(n)}catch(r){}return a}},{name:a,version:function(n){return e(n)}}],e=function(n){var a=-1;try{a=n.GetVariable("$version")}catch(r){}return a},i=function(n){var a=-1;try{a=new ActiveXObject(n)}catch(r){a={activeXError:!0}}return a};n.b=function(){if(navigator.plugins&&navigator.plugins.length>0){var a="application/x-shockwave-flash",e=navigator.mimeTypes;e&&e[a]&&e[a].enabledPlugin&&e[a].enabledPlugin.description&&(n.c=!0)}else if(-1==navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")&&window.execScript)for(var t=-1,c=0;c<r.length&&-1==t;c++){var o=i(r[c].name);o.activeXError||(n.c=!0)}}()};  
return b.c;
    })();

if(isFlashInstalled){
    // Do something with flash
    }else{
    // Don't use flash  
        }
```