# One-liner JavaScript to detect if flash is installed

Tags: javascript, flash

I know there are a bunch of posts asking this question, but all of the answers point to either swfobject or the flash detection kit.

Is there a simple one or two liner in JavaScript just to check if Flash is installed or not? I don't want to have to include a whole js library if there's an simple way to do this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-info

Comment: @Horst: Thanks.. that's what I'm looking for. Do you know if there are there any gotchas with this? Cross browser compatibility?

Comment: Nothing right now which is additional to the comments in the above question. I only remember that when we have used it we had combined two checks for some reasons I cannot recall. This was prior the iPad age, nowadays I'd check against the common [x]Pads if these are among the target audience. Maybe you combine the Flash and Browser check, e.g. once you know the browser is SAFARI/iPad you know it is not supporting Flash.

Comment: @Horst: Thanks. If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it accepted

Comment: I have summarized the comments in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a summary of the above comments as requested:

The following SO answer is applicable: [How can I detect if Flash is installed and if not, display a hidden div that informs the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-info/3336320#3336320)

Especially the comments / discussion of the above question are useful. I only remember that when we have used a Flash check we had combined two checks for some reasons I cannot recall. This was prior the iPad age, nowadays I'd check against the common [x]Pads if these are among the target audience. Maybe you combine the Flash and Browser check, e.g. once you know the browser is SAFARI/iPad you know it is not supporting Flash.

Try to encapsulate the check so you can change / extend it if required (that was useful for us).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.featureblend.com/flash_detect_1-0-4/flash_detect.js

I know you've seen it before; that's because it works.

Comment: What's the benefit of this over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-info/3336320#3336320?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it's better because it checks activeX and therefore works in IE7.

Comment: The best link is http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html