# How to check with JS if flash is installed, or not?

Tags: javascript, flash

How to check with JS if flash is installed, or not? I don't want to detect the version, or other informations. I want to check only, if it's avaiable, or not.

The swfobject library makes it (and many other things, which are unneccessary for that), but I don't want to use a library for only one function.

Comment: There is better solution to this.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you’re using Flash to progressively enhance a document, please use this script to feature detect it first.

```
var hasFlash = ((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));
```

`hasFlash` will be `true` if Flash is available, or falsy if it isn’t.

If you already have access to the Flash element you want to use then you could just do:

```
var hasFlash = 'Pan' in element;
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/675496

Comment: thanks, but when flash isn't avaiable, then it return with undefined

Comment: Does this return true when something like clicktoflash is installed? It annoys the hell out of me when I try to watch something, go to click on it to enable it, and then the site removes the flash object and tells me to install flash.

Comment: @Callum Macrae Yes. In opera with opera turbo it also returns wirt true ;)

Comment: Greatness! Helped all of my issues

Answer (score 1):

You can check if Flash is *installed* (see Mathias answer) but be aware that even if Flash is *installed* is still may be disabled (see here for examples http://blog.lroot.com/articles/techniques-to-easily-disable-flash-in-firefox-and-ie/) so your movies won't play at all.

Comment: how can I detect in JS if flash is disabled, or not?