# Use jquery when flash not available

Tags: jquery, flash

i have a slider that was built in flash but I want to replace it with a jquery slider gallery when flash is not available (such as mobile ipad etc). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/998245/1499781 - check if Flash available and display your content based on that

Comment: Out of interest - why bother using the flash version at all?

Comment: @NeilBryson had the exact same thought but didn't dare to ask :)

Comment: It's an old project that went cold but they still like the flash. (it is impressive) Thanks for the help