# Detect Flash with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect if Flash is installed and if not, display a hidden div that informs the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf)

so:

```
var _isflash = navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'];  
if(_isflash == "undefined")
{
  console.log("not exists flash")
}
else
{
  console.log("flash!") 
}
```

why this not work?

```
document.write(_isflash) // undefined
```

if flash off, _isflash = undefined...
please help me

Comment: `navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"]`

Comment: Look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf

Comment: Not sure what the python tag is doing on this question, or django, for that matter.

Comment: Whoa, what's with all the downvotes? The OP obviously doesn't have English as a first language, but they've made an effort to ask and provided some code. The question isn't perfect, but it's certainly answerable.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `"undefined"` is a string, so the two are not equal. This will do what you are trying to do:

```
if(!_isflash)
{
    console.log("not exists flash")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `_isflash` to be a string `"undefined"`. You should do this:

```
if(_isflash == undefined)
```