# Show div if no flash without using swfObject

Tags: javascript, html, flash, mobile

I am simply trying to show a div element if the user doesn't have flash installed. This is intended to work with mobiles, ipads etc.

I've already used (http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) javascript code in the past for a different purpose, but how can I get this to make a div visible instead of redirecting the page.

Some previous code I used that failed:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ){
    document.getElementById("noflash").style.display="block";
}
```

I thought this would be easy to begin with, but it's proving to be difficult. Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect if Flash is installed and if not, display a hidden div that informs the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf)

Comment: Please don't use browser sniffing, it is seriously flawed. Use feature detection.