# Is there a way to know if the Flash Player is installed with SWFObject?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, swfobject

I've been using SWFObject for years via the static publishing method, but wanted to know if there was some variable I can check to see if Flash is available/installed when the user visits a page.

I want my JavaScript or jQuery to show mobile users alternative content, which will be different than what desktop users get as alternative content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3336320/909180

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if Flash is installed and if not, display a hidden div that informs the user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf)

Answer (score 0):

Probably [`navigator.mimeTypes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.mimeTypes) could help you (if i understands your properly)

```
'application/x-shockwave-flash' in navigator.mimeTypes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way in JQuery as well using 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplugin.1.0.2.min.js"></script>`
`if ($.browser.flash == true) { alert("WE HAVE FLASH :D"); }`

For further help:
http://madhavvyas.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/detect-flash-using-jquery.html