# Create an SWF flash file that redirects to a webpage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, redirect

I try to find out, how to create a small swf file that does only one thing: redirect to another webpage.

I searched a lot, but all i found was links to outdated sites, that should contain a mini-flash-browser to show html sites inside flash, which is not the question here.

I know it's not a good solution, but I really need to redirect the users with flash to another page.

And maybe how could I create such an swf file without adobe-flash? (should be just a tiny script)

Comment: This question is too broad.   If you want to redirect users with flash installed, [better to use javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20095467/1457439).  If you must have a swf, you can download [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) and have it install the proper SDK's to make swf's.

Comment: Why this is to broad? It is a simple question that could be answered. I know JavaScript would be a solution but that is not the question here

Comment: Too broad because you're asking how to make a swf file.  Also, you haven't tried anything.   For the actual code, all you'd have to search for is "flash redirect" or "actionscript redirect" and you'll get the answer easily enough.  `navigateToURL( new URLRequest("http://google.it"), "_self");`

Comment: Cool Thanks! That is what i didn't know. With the right search words it's easy to find. If you create that as answer I will mark this solved

Comment: I do agree Javascript is probably better for the job. Is it a case where the user wants to do it in one technology only because he's afraid of all the other ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you'd have to search for is "flash redirect" or "actionscript redirect" and you'll get the answer :

```
 navigateToURL( new URLRequest("http://google.it"), "_self");
```