# JavaScript - How to detect if Flash Player is outdated or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Like in Safari browser, when a Flash player is outdated the browser shows a message :

> "The flash player you are using is outdated"

Can I auto-detect for an outdated version by using javascript?

---

*editor's note* : Issue is possibly related to this **[news](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/apple-blocks-out-of-date-flash-player-plug-ins-in-safari/)** and similar articles.

Comment: Your question is not clear... Do you want to check for installed Flash Player **version** (ie: newest _vs_ outdated, etc)? Or check if Flash plugin **software** is even installed anyways? Or you are detecting if user has web camera **hardware**? Just because you installed some plugin, this should not stop the browser itself detecting system hardware (it talks to the O.S which controls camera hardware). Is it the code in SWF application that uses a camera? Does it work if you install latest Flash Player update? What browser you testing with? Otherwise not enough useful info to help you...

Comment: Anyways you could try the suggestion in this **[Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990673/2057709)** or directly check it's inspiration **[Flash Detect](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html)**

Comment: I wanted to check whether flash is outdated or not.

Comment: What does that even mean exactly? "outdated" is a concept in people's heads, so how can a machine detect an abstract human concept?? Are you actually looking for user's Flash version, is that it? In that **Flash Detect** link, the "demo" is actually a live test running from their linked JS files and you can see it detects version. What condition (for you) makes it outdated vs not outdated? It shouldn't matter anyway since most major browsers (Chrome, FF and Edge) do an auto-update to latest release of Flash Player.

Comment: Like in mac safari, when a flash player is outdated the browser show a message "The flash player you are using is outdated", can i detect this in javascript?

Comment: aah, So it is **version** you want to check after all... Try storing the latest Adobe version number in some var of your JS/html. You can find number via **[this page](http://www.adobe.com/uk/software/flash/about/index.html)**. Up to you how you extract the number text (via i-frame & search?, via source code check? via PHP?). Then use that library to detect user's own version of Flash. Compare the two numbers as to whether user's version is older than known latest version (your number). If older (smaller than `<`) then call it "outdated" if you want...

Comment: I tried to edit your question. Fix or add any relevant details. Show code of what you've tried towards this task (version comparison), and someone will help you fix any issues.