# Video JS prompt if flash is not installed

Tags: javascript, flash, video, video.js, flv

Is there a way to get videojs to detect if there is no flash player installed and prompt the user to install it? I have been through the docs and try to use `techOrder` but it didn't work.

Comment: You may or may not want/need to do that, because the major browsers are dropping support for flash-plugins.  [But, maybe I miss-understand the full context of your question. I'm assuming that you're also sourcing an alternate video file of a more common technology, such as MP4 or WebM, etc. !?!?]

Answer (score 2):

Use one of these ([How can I detect if Flash is installed and if not, display a hidden div that informs the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf)) methods – not anything specifically to do with the `videojs` "[techorder](http://Playback%20Technology)". That's for silently falling back to use an alternate tech:

> By default Video.js performs "Tech-first" ordering when it searches
>   for a source/tech combination to play videos. This means that if you
>   have two sources and two techs, video.js will try to play each video
>   with the first tech in the techOrder option property before moving on
>   to try the next playback technology.