# In javascript, can I ask if the browser has flash enabled for a specific (not current) website?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser

We have a partner site (partner-example.com) with a product that uses Flash.  We have a page on our own website (example.com) which sends the user there when they press a button.

I'd like to try to find out if the browser is going to actually let them use that other site, ie if they have Flash enabled for that site, before sending them there, so I can show an extra message saying "Please note - it looks like Flash is currently not enabled for our partner site - you will need to have Flash enabled for "partner-example.com".

Is this possible?

Comment: Flash will soon no longer be supported in browsers. I would suggest a pop-up that informs the user how to enable flash vs. checking to see if its enabled. Most browsers now have it set to an 'Ask everytime' sort of thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245, second answer from top. But actually yeah, Jay Mason says it right, browsers now ask user themselves, you don't need to annoy user once more.

Comment: @JayMason i think you're probably right, I was just wondering if it was possible really.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible - you can use several Libs to do that ... e.g SWF Object or this one: http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html

It is not necessary to test it for another website ;) if the client is able to see flash content on your site - he is able to see it everywhere.

Comment: It might be enabled on my website but disabled on the other site, though.

Comment: this isn't a valid user-interaction. if you browse through the web and have flash installed - you can use it :) the scenario someone is on your website click on the link and uninstalls flash ... isn't a real one ;) on most browsers the user has to activate the flash player to see the content - but this is a security thing - so you cant remove or "hack" it

Comment: I'm not talking about Flash being installed, I'm talking about it being enabled, or "allowed", to use Chrome's language.  Chrome routinely disables flash now, even when it has been allowed before, for a given website.    For any given website, it can flip between the enabled and disabled state easily.

Comment: hi @MaxWilliams - okay - but if I knew it right - chrome "disallow" it by default - so if you are entering a site flash is disabled and you get an ui-box to click to activate/allow it. this site appears in your chrome settings - I'm sure you can't read this information via JS or something else - this might be a security issue. Perhaps it is possible if you make a Chrome-Extension but this is not the thing you want. ;) so - sorry. i think you have to clear it on your site - via content - inform the customers by clicking the link they should activate flash