# Can't detect the exact browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to detect the user's browser. So I checked my code in Chrome and Edge. It doesn't work in both.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let userAgentString = navigator.userAgent;
  console.log(userAgentString);
  let isChrome = userAgentString.indexOf("Chrome") > -1;

  if (isChrome) {
    $('#chromeUser').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

It makes the div `chromeUser` display to `block` in both browsers. It means that it doesn't know which browser I'm from.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Your code appears to be correct, how is it not working?

Comment: @Perhapsyouseethisname. that what I don't understand.

Comment: What problem are you **actually** trying to solve by doing browser detection?  If Edge is missing some feature that Chrome has, you should try to determine if that **feature** is available.  Otherwise you are going to play whack-a-mole adjusting for each specific browser.

Comment: @zero298 Sorry but I'm really don't know about this comparison between browsers with javascript code. where to start?

Comment: What we meant here by feature detection is that normally you'd for example want to show element X on browser Y because only that browser supports element X. In that case, you should instead detect _whether the browser (whichever it is) supports X_ and not whether it is exactly browser Y. (Also, tomorrow browser Z may also start supporting X...)

Comment: However, now that you mentioned it's about showing a Flash deprecation message, this is entirely irrelevant anyway, because _all browsers will drop Flash_.

Comment: Edge, Opera and Brave are the same engine as Chrome, IE support for Flash is separately dropped, Firefox [drops it too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Roadmap) and any browser still supporting it after Dec. 2020 is a bad old browser which you shouldn't support anyway, because it means it'll be an insecure browser. Because [Adobe will stop shipping security updates for Flash at the end of 2020](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/)!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge is now a version of Chromium, and its user agent is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) *Chrome*/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36 Edg/81.0.416.62", so your code is identifying it as Chrome. Are there any specific issues you are having with other browsers? If so, you should try to detect those issues or features instead of detecting browsers, which is a bad practice.

Comment: So what your suggestion?

Comment: Don't use browser detection. Use feature detection.

Comment: Are there any specific issues?

Comment: @Perhapsyouseethisname. yes. I can't recognize if you from Chrome or Edge

Comment: Which is irrelevant. If I change my user agent string in either of those browsers you can't detect it either. And what will you do with any other Chromium-based browser, say _Chromium_? Or Opera or Brave, for that matter.

Comment: What specific problems do you have on non-chrome browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to test on another browser. 
Edge is based on Chromium (chrome)

The user-agent looks like : 
`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43`

read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-string

Comment: I'm tell you what. Google Chrome will stop support flash files at the end of 2020. I want to check if user is from Google Chrome and show a message in accordance. did you think Edge will block flash too?

Comment: [Yes.](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/08/30/update-removing-flash-microsoft-edge-internet-explorer/#HQ8sCXmIatAsCcLU.97)

Comment: You should probably show whatever message this is for _all_ browsers because eventually every good, maintained browser will remove Flash soon. [Flash is dead](https://www.wired.com/story/adobe-finally-kills-flash-dead/) and Adobe won't support it anymore after the end of the year, so no updates or anything, meaning it would be irresponsible by any browser vendor to keep supporting it, it would be a security nightmare.

Comment: At this time the support for flash is on a client to client basis. meaning - you can have Chrome where it is disabled by default, or you may have a browser where the user enabled flash specifically from the browser's settings. There are scripts you can run to check if flash is enabled.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998245/how-can-i-detect-if-flash-is-installed-and-if-not-display-a-hidden-div-that-inf